# Document score

Tags: lucene

I'm trying to read document score of lucene search results.

I get a set of document scores through the hits object when I use the following method :
Hits hits = IndexSearcher.search(myQuery);

However,if i use the method:
searcher.search(myQuery, hitsCollector);

I get a totally different set of document scores through the hitCollector.hits object

Am I missing something here?

Thanks!

Comment: This user seems to be re-asking the same or similar questions repeatedly: http://stackoverflow.com/users/41625/meyahoocomaodzxyowykprbavs5sf701zowgzpc3svjv8

Look at the posting record before taking the time to answer...

Answer (score 2):

The scores returned by a Hits object are normalized, i.e. they are always in the range [0, 1], with the highest score close to or at 1. The scores given to a HitCollector object are raw, i.e. not normalized. Also, the list of documents in a Hits object is sorted by decreasing scores. A HitCollector object gets document-score pairs in some random order.